# Настройка дедика для отправки почты на mail.ru

Tags: vds, email, sendmail

Всем привет! Сегодня вот обнаружил что наш дедик не отправляет почту на mail.ru. На gmail почта уходит нормально.

Вот отчет об ошибке: http://s006.radikal.ru/i213/1401/78/abb8c23973de.png

Супер навыками администрирования я не обладаю, но через SSH к серверу доберусь и какие-то несложные действия могу сделать.

Также есть доступ к WHM Panel. Возможно там нужно какие-то настройки прописать?

Подскажите как быстрее всего настроить сервер, чтобы отправлял почту на mail.ru

Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

**unroutable sender address** говорит о том, что mail.ru не смог проверить маршрут до отправителя.

Возможные причины: Не существует или не делегирован домен, на который посылается почта Для домена неправильно или непрописаны MX, A или PTR-записи.

что говорит

```
dig +short mx <домен>
```

Answer (score 0):

Так же к ответу @ArcherGodson добавлю про желательное наличие [DKIM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) и [SPF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework). Эти настройки на сервере помогают чаще всего избавиться от попадания в спам и блэк листы.